# Kafka select KSQL query on table return nothing

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

i try repeat create Ktable and select by manual 
https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/create-a-table/

Select from topic `kafkacat -b broker:9092 -t videos`:

```
{"VideoId":"304b3306-c3d6-47c8-a936-c0e2d4d375ee","UserId":"7c8266d7-fea7-49c1-8fc2-aff47a9c19e5"}
```

Create Ktable from topic

```
create table videos_table (VideoId varchar, UserId varchar) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'videos', KEY = 'VideoId', VALUE_FORMAT='json');
```

Info : `show tables`;

```
 Table Name  | Kafka Topic | Format | Windowed 
-----------------------------------------------
 VIDEOS_TABLE | videos       | JSON   | false    
-----------------------------------------------
```

Select from table: `SELECT * FROM videos_table EMIT CHANGES`;

I have nothing on screen. Then i insert new msg to topic, i see it in kafkacat, but this select no print nothing.  On manual they have result:

[screen from manual, they have result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOGAD.png)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of ksqlDB are you using? Are there any errors in the ksqlDB server log?

Comment: cp-ksqldb-server:5.5.0. I use docker, what is command for logs ? or can cat as linux /var/logs/ksqldb/ ?

Comment: `docker logs -f <container name>`

Comment: I'm not seeing any of `VIDEOS_TABLE` in the link you shared. Maybe the example was updated on the site.

Comment: It's not clear from your output above what the key of the kafka records is.  Can you add the `-K` switch to kafkacat and update the output?

It's important for the key of the Kafka record to be set if `CREATE TABLE` is to work in ksqlDB.

Comment: Oh i find problem in logs. Messages was without key in topic and skip processing. I think "key" is then we create table KEY = 'VideoId' getting from body. thx @RobinMoffatt AndrewCoates  Giorgos Myrianthous

Answer (score 0):

By default, ksqlDB reads from the end of a topic. A query does not return results if no new messages are being written to the topic.

Make sure that `auto.offset.reset` is set to `earliest` so that `ksqldb` reads from the beginning of a topic. Finally re-run your queries and all the data should now be visible.

---

```
SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';
```

Comment: yes i find this option and try. But nothing , i insert new msg in topic after SELECT  query running, but print nothing